# Unique colors for each series in ggplot in graph and legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend

I want to use `ggplot` to create a graph that plots individual data points in one color and the mean in another color, then have a legend that explains the colors.  Here are three attempts that don't quite work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
# Create new tbl_df with average hp for each transmission
avghp <- mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>%  summarize(hp=mean(hp))

# Correct dots and colors, no legend
g1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=am, y=hp)) +
  geom_point(colour="blue" )+
  geom_point(data=avghp, colour="red", size=4)

# Legend, but colors changed
g2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=am, y=hp)) +
  geom_point(aes( colour="Individual"))+
  geom_point(data=avghp, aes(colour="Average"), size=4)

# Correct colors in graph, but not in legend
g3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=am, y=hp)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill="Individual"), colour="blue")+
  geom_point(data=avghp, aes(fill="Average"), colour="red", size=4)
```

`g1` shows the individual data points in blue, and the averages in red, but there's no legend because the colors aren't in an `aes()`.  `g2` creates  the legend, but doesn't use the same colors as in `g1`. `g3` moves the definitions of the colors outside the `aes()` and used `fill()` to create the legend, but then the dots on the legend are both blue.

How can I create something like `g3` but where the legend shows a red dot for the average hp, and a blue for the individuals?  Or, how can I specify specific colors in `g2`?

Comment: In theory there's no point to add legend for blue color points as they belong to same group. Usually you add this info to title "Scatterplot of something"

Comment: That's a good tip most of the time, but 1) My audience needs a little hand-holding, and 2) This was the simplification of what I'm trying to do. In some cases I'll have three overlaid graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set color manually using `scale_color_manual`

```
g2 + scale_color_manual("Legend", values = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]